# pyinstaller --onefile is not including all necessary dependencies

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile a python script into an executable using pyinstaller --onefile. However, one necessary package, *geemap*, doesn't seem to be included, despite being an `import` in the script.

Is it possible to force-add custom packages?

Every time I run the .pyc file on a clean PC, it says:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'geemap'`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=geemap

This should force-add the package.

Comment: I did try this before, but unfortunately adding --hidden-import=geemap still resulted in the same error with the module not being found! Hope there is another way

Comment: What else have you tried? Have you tried adding it into the spec file and rerunning the pyinstaller --onefile command? Are you bundling the script in a virtual environment?

Comment: I added 'geemap' as a hiddenimport in the spec file and ran pyinstaller on the spec file, but still geemap is not included. I am not running in a virtual environment, but in the global environment.

Comment: @Oliver any solutions ?